# How to handle Storyboard ViewControllers in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have added 3 Views in ViewController, if 2nd/middle view has no text or it has one line text, the height of the middle view should be 30  and last view should move up at run time.

[image]

Comment: middle view contains a label?

Comment: green yellow and  orange colors are views

Comment: in that yellow view "nothing here.." is label.

Comment: how many lines of text can the middle view hold? maximum?

Comment: after run the programe  middle view should be height i need 30. and below view move up adjust heights

Comment: it have one line only.!!!

Comment: but what will happen when there are more than 1 line?

Comment: i need this  task in my project how to handle i dnt know

Comment: agar 1 line se jyada ho toh?

Comment: i have taken UITextView in view controller some time i'm getting one matter so i need's to textview hight 30 R 40 and remaining below  view views move up!!

Comment: Middle view can only have maximum one line of text?not more than one line?

Answer (score 1):

```
ADD THIS TO YOUR CODE:

CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score -1):

ADD this CODE

[yourlabel sizeToFit ];
or
[yourView sizeToFit];